# TwitPic API Isn't Responding Correctly - Keeps Returning 401

Tags: c#, .net, twitpic

So, I've still been trying to make this Twitter client, and I'm working on the image attachments for it, but I can't get the TwitPic API to work with oAuthTwitter (The oAuth framework that I use for the client).

Here's the code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            filePath = filePath.Replace("\\", "/");
            sb.AppendFormat("?message={1}&media={0}&key={2}&consumer_token={3}&consumer_secret={4}&oauth_token={5}&oauth_secret={6}",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode("@" + filePath), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tweet), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(apiKey), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oAuth.ConsumerKey), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oAuth.ConsumerSecret), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oAuth.Token), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oAuth.TokenSecret));
            string req = sb.ToString();
            debu.Write("[DEBUG]     Request: " + req);
            string response = "hai";
            try
            {
                response = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.POST, "http://api.twitpic.com/1/uploadAndPost.json",
                    req);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { debu.Write("[FATAL]   " + e.Message); return false; }
            debu.Write("[DEBUG]     Response: " + response);

            return true;
```

The debug file reads the following:

```
[2/12/2011 3:27:30 PM] [DEBUG]     Request: ?message=This+is+testing+the+image+uploader+for+TwitterAPI&media=C%3a%2fIcon.png&key=33a6804da25ac80ff3d7ba985c6e9a96&consumer_token=EPYl2jwBzUOANlRHC67Q&consumer_secret=yfOz603EbkDat1PBEq05jhvkFuYNvTPwZI1wk2uc&oauth_token=37993700-dU1ecaBlPLBFnVj4LKu6TG5yQRmmlCGr2FX97EqM&oauth_secret=4z6738kJwJaGlJgwiJ5x20prCGccpipcUdnzVpfS6U
[2/12/2011 3:27:31 PM] [FATAL]   The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Any suggestions on why this might not be working?

Answer (score 0):

You are URL encoding your complete query string.

This means that things like `&` get encoded as `%26` and `=` as `%3D`. This is wrong, as your parameters will not be seen as parameters by the API.

You should encode the parameter names and values only.

Comment: Okay, but when I encode just the variables, it gives me a 400, meaning that I'm missing some variables when I'm not.

Comment: @sammarks - what does the request look like when you do this? By the way, did you look at the meaning of the different 400 errors as defined by the API?

Comment: @Oded - There's only one definition for it, that I haven't included enough variables. Here's the request: [2/12/2011 3:09:15 PM] [DEBUG]     Request: ?message=This+is+testing+the+image+uploader+for+TwitterAPI&media=%40%2fIcon.png&key=33a6804da25ac80ff3d7ba985c6e9a96&consumer_token=EPYl2jwBzUOANlRHC67Q&consumer_secret=yfOz603EbkDat1PBEq05jhvkFuYNvTPwZI1wk2uc&oauth_token=37993700-dU1ecaBlPLBFnVj4LKu6TG5yQRmmlCGr2FX97EqM&oauth_secret=4z6738kJwJaGlJgwiJ5x20prCGccpipcUdnzVpfS6U - And it still doesn't work even without the ? at the beginning.

Comment: @sammarks - please _edit_ your question and post it there. And delete the comment - this is unreadable as a comment.

Comment: @sammarks - Your media parameter appears incorrect. When decoded I see it as `@/Icon.png`. Are you sure this is right?

Comment: There, edited the post and changed the code and request code to match my results.

Comment: @Oded - I assume so. That's how it looked in the API and the cURL command that was supplied on the API docs: http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/1/uploadAndPost/

Comment: @sammarks - Try without it. `@` has special meaning in a URL.

Comment: I edited the post to contain the updated request. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Oded - I didn't think it was necessary. Updated the post to contain the new request.

Comment: @sammarks - If I understand the curl command correctly, all parameters apart from `media` and `key` are supposed to be on the headers. Why are you not using the C# library that they are linking to? http://twipli.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Oded - That library requires a Twitter username and password, and I don't believe it supports posting directly to Twitter. I'll try it again and see.